# Google Analytics doesn't display data of the activities present in the library project

Tags: android, google-analytics, library-project

I have a important library project that is used by some projects.
When I implement google analytics in the library project it works fine. But When I implement same to the main projects who use this library project, It only shows analytics data for the activities that are only present in the package.

e.g. case 1 : implementing Google analytics in library project

> works Fine

case 2: implementing Google analytics in main project

> data showing for only the package in which we have configured
>   **com.mainproject**.MyActivity
>
> No data displays for in library package **com.librarypackage**.MyLibraryActivity

Any easy solution for this so that I can get analytics data for the library project as well that is for a different package.

Comment: there are many possible soutions like extending each class from the library package in the child package so that now all the classes will now be in the child project not anymore used in the library project.